# GREP_COLORS does not work on GNU grep Mac OS

Tags: grep

On Linux, I get beautiful coloring that makes the file name and line numbers easy to distinguish from the file content:

[image]

I have set `GREP_COLORS` on Mac OS X for my GNU grep installation (via homebrew) but it gets ignored. I just get coloring of the matching text which is more limited.

#### Version info

```
/Volumes/numerous/usr/local/homebrew/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin/grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.7
Packaged by Homebrew
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

```
GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
```

[image]

#### Incorrect answer

Use `--color=always`. I'm not talking about highlighting matches. I'm talking about component coloring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it looks like it works. Somehow the `grep` being picked from my `PATH` was the BSD version after I relocated my Homebrew folder (and I probably didn't `brew install grep` thinking it was part of coreutils or gnutls), and my example screenshot didn't have `--color`

[image]